# Two Services HTTP google compute engine

Tags: apache, tomcat, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine

I need start two services HTTP in same instances on google compute engine (Apache HTTP and Glassfish HTTP both port 80). I've already looked for port forwarding and ip, but found it all very confusing. Has anyone ever needed this kind of environment? Could you help me with a step by step?

Answer (score 1):

You can't start two services on the same port. You will need to redirect the HTTP request to to the Tomcat. In order to achieve that you will need to configure your Apache as a  reverse proxy. Here you can read more about it [1].

This is am example extracted from the Apache documentation [2]:

```
# mod_proxy setup.
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /webapps http://localhost:8080
ProxyPassReverse /webapps http://localhost:8080

<Location "/webapps">
  # Configurations specific to this location. Add what you need.
  # For instance, you can add mod_proxy_html directives to fix
  # links in the HTML code. See link at end of this page about using
  # mod_proxy_html.

  # Allow access to this proxied URL location for everyone.
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Location>
```

And here [3] you can find a step by step tutorial.

[1] https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html
[2] https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/TomcatReverseProxy
[3] https://rvdb.wordpress.com/2012/04/26/reverse-proxying-tomcat-webapps-behind-apache/